# Mobile App: A Detailed View with a Fixed Top

Tags: mobile, navigation, mobile-application, back-button

I am working out the details on how a user can see a 'Detailed View' of something, and then navigate back to the 'List View'.  This is usually simple, using the Navigation Bar in iOS or the Back Button for Android, but the screen has a fixed top.  There is a Map that will still be on the top of the page.

See here:
[image: Screenshots of list view and detail view with fixed header]

I could put a 'Back' button in the top left of the Navigation bar but that might seem strange since the user is not on a new screen, just the content under the 'FIXED' section changed.

Is there "best practice" to provide the user with a way to go back to the List View?

Answer (score 1):

**If the content length of detail section is not too long**, I would suggest to follow an accordeon mechanism.

This means, a click on a label toggles its content just under the label. If you click on another one, opened content previously will be hidden and the appropriate one will be toggled.

By this way you don't need a switch to a new detail page and user is still able to see the other options (labels).

Answer (score 0):

*Sorry if I do some english errors, I'm french.*
**The first thing that came to my mind was putting the navigation bar under the fixed element**, *although right now I think that it's pretty strange too... I am interested by what other guys will answer to your question that is a pretty complex one.*
*By the way, I don't know if it was intentional or not, but don't label the back button "Back", label it with the explicit name of what the user will be back to.*

Comment: Hi Trevor Anne Denise,  you can leave a comment if you are not trying to answer the question.